# SAP BO - Compare values between rows and conditionally display

Tags: business-objects

I have a request where I need to create an integrity report where I am looking at sales data and verifying that the payment terms are consistent on all items (rows).

Sample data:

```
Sales # | Line # | Terms Code 
100     | 1.0    |  N90
100     | 2.0    |  N90
101     | 1.0    |  N60
101     | 2.0    |  P45
101     | 3.0    |  N60
```

Notice that on Sales Order `101`, line `2.0` has a different terms code. I need to detect that and only display order 101 on the report.

I was looking at using the PREVIOUS operator in a variable like this:

```
=If(Previous([Payment Terms Code])=[Payment Terms Code]) Then 0 Else 1
```

but that looks at the Order `100` line `2.0` and would flag it incorrectly.

I am not sure how I can do this, but maybe using the IN operator some how. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So is appropriate to describe the requirement as you need to see any Sales Orders that have more than one distinct terms code?  If so, you can accomplish it like this:

Create a new variable:
`Terms Count =Count([Terms Code]) in ([Sales #])`

Add this object to the report.  You should see "1" for all of the 100 records, and "2" for the 101 records.

Finally, add a filter to the report on Trans Count > 1.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the `Previous()` function is:

```
Previous(dimension|measure|Self [;Row|col][;(reset_dims)][;offset][;NoNull])
```

The third parameter, `reset_dims` allows you to specify when the list of dimensions used to reset the calculation.

Thus, your formula would then be:

```
Previous([Payment Terms Code]; ([Sales #];[Line #]))
```

Notes:

- You must always place dimensions in parentheses even if there is only one dimension in the list of reset dimensions.
- When you specify a set of reset dimensions you must separate them with semi-colon